# aws custom attributes not recognized in role assigned policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito, amazon-iam

Objective: assign via a cognito userpool + identitypool a user with a custom attribute: tenantId access to his own bucket folder in S3: s3://[tenantId]/*

I've configured:

- a userpool with a customer attribute tenantId and gave the app client read rights to that attribute
- attached an identity pool
- created a role and attached that to the identity pool for authenticated users

Via a login page I've retrieved a valid idToken, and given that idToken, I execute the following code (simplified example without error handling etc):

```
const REGION            = '...';
const USERPOOLID        = '...';
const IDENTITYPOOLID    = '...';
const BUCKET            = '...';
const KEY               = '...';
const TEST_JWT_ID_TOKEN = 'xxx.yyy.zzz';

AWS               = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.region = REGION;

const cognitoIdentityObj = {
    IdentityPoolId: IDENTITYPOOLID,
    Logins        : {
        [`cognito-idp.${REGION}.amazonaws.com/${USERPOOLID}`]: TEST_JWT_ID_TOKEN
    },
};
AWS.config.credentials   = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials(cognitoIdentityObj);
AWS.config.credentials.get(function (err) {
    if (!err) {
        const accessKeyId     = AWS.config.credentials.accessKeyId;
        const secretAccessKey = AWS.config.credentials.secretAccessKey;
        const sessionToken    = AWS.config.credentials.sessionToken;
        if (accessKeyId && secretAccessKey && sessionToken) {
            const AWS_S3 = new AWS.S3({accessKeyId, secretAccessKey, sessionToken});
            const params = {
                Bucket: BUCKET,
                Key   : KEY
            };
            AWS_S3.getObject(params, function (err, data) {
                if (err) {
                    // err is an Access Denied
                    console.error(err);
                } else {
                    console.log(data);
                }
            })
        }
    }
})
```

The TEST_JWT_ID_TOKEN contains a valid ID Token, and via the identity pool when signed in the user is attached to a role. That role has a policy with this definition:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::<BUCKET>/${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:custom:tenantId}/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

However when I try to read from that bucket, I get an access denied, adding a resource line in the policy as in:

```
arn:aws:s3:::<BUCKET>/*
```

does the trick, so I'm fairly sure the whole setup with the userpool, the identity pool, the role and the policy is working. However the attribute: ${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:custom:tenantId} does not seem to get recognised/not evaluated or ...

Comment: Seems you want to do s3 protected by cognito identity id? And what is the variable "KEY"?

Comment: Correct, protect s3 by cognito, the variable KEY is the S3 key where the content is stored (path + file /[tenantId]/folder/file.png)

Comment: were you able to find out why ? i am facing the same issue with policy not recognizing custom attributes but it works with ${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}

Comment: Yes, custom attributes can not be used in ARN ... Let's see if I can find that article...

Comment: Mhmmm slightly different route... https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/using-attributes-for-access-control-policy-example.html search continues

Comment: Can't find the AWS docs, was very very well hidden ... As I recall, sone standard attributes can be used, custom attribs not.

Comment: @Paul have same issue, how did you solve this one?

Comment: @GivenNyauyanga I didn't, custom attributes can not be used in such sense.

Comment: I found a way to do it using your link https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/using-attributes-for-access-control-policy-example.html and some more googling. If you read a few docs about ABAC you will understand the idea around it.

Comment: @Given NICE! things actually changed for the better, in Jan 2021 this wasn't possible, great that you didn't listen to me, I think you should create an answer, which will imho should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well, what you need is adding policy condition on IAM Authenticated Role policy and limit the principal access on s3 policy. Check this out for available condition keys [Actions, resources, and condition keys for Amazon S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_amazons3.html). I use prefix key for this case, in another case I will use ExistingObjectTag.

I never known with the term of "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:custom:tenantId". In my projects, I am using "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub" for the identity role id reference and "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:aud" for the group role.

For the IAM Authenticated Role policy, I put the statement like so :

```
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "s3:ListBucket"
        ],
        "Condition": {
            "StringLike": {
                "s3:prefix": ["${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}"]
            }
        },
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<BUCKET_NAME>"
    },
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "s3:GetObject"
        ],
        "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::<BUCKET_NAME>/${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}/*"]
    }
]
```

And on the s3 policy, I will limit the principal access for the authenticated role only :

```
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": <IAM_AUTH_ROLE_ARN>
        },
        "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<BUCKET_NAME>"
    },
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": <IAM_AUTH_ROLE_ARN>
        },
        "Action": "s3:GetObject",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<BUCKET_NAME>/*"
    }
]
```

The official documentation [Amazon S3: Allows Amazon Cognito users to access objects in their bucket](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_examples_s3_cognito-bucket.html)

Answer (score 0):

there is a good article here explaining how you can use custom cognito attributes to restrict access to bucket prefixes.

https://www.chaosgears.com/post/enabling-amazon-cognito-identity-pools-and-aws-iam-to-perform-attribute-based-access-control

The attributes for access control can be mapped to your custom cognito attributes and can then be called via AWS IAM as IAM Policy Variable ${aws:PrincipalTag/tenantId}. you then challenge the policy variable with the s3 prefix. Hence your s3 prefixes are separated by tenantId (i.e - in your s3 bucket there are separate folders (prefix) for each tenant).

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "s3:PutObject",
            "s3:GetObject",
            "s3:DeleteObject"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET-NAME/*"
        ],
        "Condition": {
            "ForAnyValue:StringEquals": {
                "aws:PrincipalTag/tenantId": "${s3:prefix}"
            }
        }
    }
]
```

}